# PayPal encrypted button as text link

Tags: paypal

I use PayPal Api to create encrypted BuyNow buttons. The Api return button as form HTML code.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

The problem is that I do not want to use FORM for paypal buttons and also I do not find a way to change default paypal button which is embedded in form html code. I would like to use encrypted paypal button as simple text link.

I have tried to just copy all form variables and build url with parameters like

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&encrypted=-----BEGIN PKCS7-----MIIIWwYJKoZIhvcNAQcEoIIITDCCCEgCAQExggE6MIIBNgIBAD.....
```

Unfortunately it do not work. Maybe someone has solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the BMCreateButton API call, instead of BUTTONTYPE=ENCRYPTED, set BUTTONTYPE=HOSTED. It will be the same security-wise, but it would also return an 'EMAILLINK', which you could then use.

BUTTONTYPE=ENCRYPTED unfortunately will not return an EMAILLINK.

Additionally, if you include the full encrypted text inside your link, you may well run into a LimitRequestLine limitation in Apache (default: 8190), depending on your Apache configuration.
It's just much, much better to keep the URL as short as possible.

Comment: It is much better to keep the URL as short as possible!! And also to have someone else do the work! BMCreateButton to create a hosted button is definitely the best option

Answer (score 2):

You copied the link wrong. [It will work fine.](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&encrypted=-----BEGIN%20PKCS7-----MIIIWwYJKoZIhvcNAQcEoIIITDCCCEgCAQExggE6MIIBNgIBADCBnjCBmDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExETAPBgNVBAcTCFNhbiBKb3NlMRUwEwYDVQQKEwxQYXlQYWwsIEluYy4xFjAUBgNVBAsUDXNhbmRib3hfY2VydHMxFDASBgNVBAMUC3NhbmRib3hfYXBpMRwwGgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg1yZUBwYXlwYWwuY29tAgEAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIGAWicsbzx8E3DiwoiAmsPDgFMXMXw2Vv4brJMg0h%2b4q3XDYZIlUmqe68cz/G98LcdjCRPzdj8ysAL9omG%2bCajwB%2b6Lh1gU8XnqolRbY0qrj515o2aUbR4mIZnRVMpFakSuX/xB/yvy%2b%2bTjr/1bCltQAKDGltKO3SC4lAWuZmOnRwMxCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIIBpQYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBQGCCqGSIb3DQMHBAjebWIsZ7c0uYCCAYD1BBI60xmtUikWJcD9qEVSQAwTQQQP4gHXND31K3fHootn0Tp84WE8JBDYnYB8PXegdvZCTEpGd4%2bLEmz/20B%2bLL/rhqlphri3RmatJpPBI5YxpKKxslVskqQgvW6C0YhTaTCxqaU3e5jMVm5kAfDE1BvJnjTDDzie5mAMp0XutUu0oz7Fj3dn%2bh/BaxfVYLrwDo3pEOD307j%2b6PX%2bRI3KAsbMopFJ2RsmsBQmSLDgkfuHUr9zUYrySKKWWHKAI0llg0hlhXmNyaia3ukKOtdj0mEtkjpnbtbRaUOCscm9TBo6fxtnWlvhhO0iaLRSQEgeoe94dJg%2bfeZ0/7yTa1l5Estb6SqdXKtzsVBnYFAiUpmIYl6u7Tk0ubaR/wPH8zeF1oPOfhnSMI8PNrdNvE3s4s9VQNTSA7I5jYOux78H44U3cuK5YNINqMaDMc0EEirV9YBm39agLLKzAr%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%2b1%2bL/EjpO1jeqPaJC1fDi%2bcC6t6tTbQ55Od4poT8xjSzNH5S48iHdZh0C7EqfE1MPCc2coJqCSpDqxmOrO%2b9QXsjHWAnx6sb6foHHpsPm7WgQyUmDsNwTWT3OGR398ERmBzzcoL5owf3zBSpRP0NlTWonPMCAwEAAaOB%2bDCB9TAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUgy4i2asqiC1rp5Ms81Dx8nfVqdIwgcUGA1UdIwSBvTCBuoAUgy4i2asqiC1rp5Ms81Dx8nfVqdKhgZ6kgZswgZgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMREwDwYDVQQHEwhTYW4gSm9zZTEVMBMGA1UEChMMUGF5UGFsLCBJbmMuMRYwFAYDVQQLFA1zYW5kYm94X2NlcnRzMRQwEgYDVQQDFAtzYW5kYm94X2FwaTEcMBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYNcmVAcGF5cGFsLmNvbYIBADAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBAFc288DYGX%2bGX2%2bWP/dwdXwficf%2brlG%2b0V9GBPJZYKZJQ069W/ZRkUuWFQ%2bOpd2yhPpneGezmw3aU222CGrdKhOrBJRRcpoO3FjHHmXWkqgbQqDWdG7S%2b/l8n1QfDPp%2bjpULOrcnGEUY41ImjZJTylbJQ1b5PBBjGiP0PpK48cdFMYIBpDCCAaACAQEwgZ4wgZgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMREwDwYDVQQHEwhTYW4gSm9zZTEVMBMGA1UEChMMUGF5UGFsLCBJbmMuMRYwFAYDVQQLFA1zYW5kYm94X2NlcnRzMRQwEgYDVQQDFAtzYW5kYm94X2FwaTEcMBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYNcmVAcGF5cGFsLmNvbQIBADAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcNMTIwODI5MDg1NTU1WjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQUaBaJ4m2GzLbeacAcXs2DCghZIEgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEgYB3vXv0Qlqda8ejg8FWLie/fvC9p8sk/TP%2bgBXnxi5sNPM0N9NTHp3Epu8qZR9FJVctrBkeF5BosIqhCfNe9HV12PFbv7N9jXSNJ8Dkr0TVtlAWhSmoeaDDHSm3uhYYJ4wcWImLSGufOdoE/cyGys8rxv7noJN6YjTfbgXbum9DZQ==-----END%20PKCS7-----%0D%0A)

However, a hosted button is much much much better. And editable via the [ButtonManager API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ButtonMgrAPIIntro).

Comment: There's no way for me to tell that based on your above information. You can easily check by comparing whatever link you used to the link I provided above.

Comment: Yes you can edit a hosted button via the API, but if you're doing that be advised your edits affect *all* users after you make the edit and not just the one you're currently processing the payment for - so best to avoid if you're dynamically changing the price.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I `urlencode`d the encrypted value and it worked. I hope this helps for anyone else having the same issue that does not want to use the API to make hosted buttons.